# How to check whether a form control is disabled or not in reactive forms

Tags: typescript, angular8

Is there a way in angular to check whether a form control is disabled ?

```
this.form.get("nationality").disable()
```

disabled this control.

Can i check whether this control is disable on reset method. If its disabled , don't need to reset the value.

How can I check that.

```
onReset(){
 if(this.form.get("nationality").isDisable()){// its wrong
let name =this.form.get("nationality").value;
}else{
let name = null;
}
 this.form.reset({
        name: name
    });

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Form controls do have a `disabled` property, so for example

```
if(!myForm.controls['myControl'].disabled){
  myForm.controls['myControl'].reset();
}
```

will only reset the form control if it was not disabled.

See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl for more information

Answer (score 2):

Log your FormControl, it has a property called `disabled`:

[image]

which you can check like so:

```
// this is the control that we're using
formControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');

// and this is the check that we're doing:
if (this.formControl.disabled) {
  // do your magic here
}
```